# Where is the best place to catch useragent?

Tags: themes, browser-compatibility

I want to add this code:

```
if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-8]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    // if IE<=8
    include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/noie.php' );
    exit;
}
else
{
    // if IE>8
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302302/php-if-internet-explorer-6-7-8-or-9)

So I let users know that my website (wordpress theme) is not supporting IE 8 and below.

Where is the best place to put this code? Is it in function.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter `template_include`. `wp-includes/template-loader.php` is where template is included.